# Using $.proxy with dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind a click event to an element that is dynamically created, which normally works fine, however when I throw `$.proxy` into the mix, it no longer works. I can get `$.proxy` working separately, and I can get click events on dynamic elements also working separately, but when I try to combine them together to do what I need, it doesn't work. Why is this?

```
selectProduct: function(){
    console.log("hello");
},

binds: function() {
    // When user selects a product
    $('#sfProductList').on('click', '.lm-fancy-select__option', function(){
        $.proxy(this.selectProduct, this);
    });
}
```

Also tried

```
binds: function() {    
  // When user selects a product
  $('#sfProductList').on('click', '.lm-fancy-select__option', $.proxy(this.selectProduct, this));
}
```

If the element is not dynamically created, then this works:

```
binds: function() {
    // When user selects a product
    $('#sfProductList .lm-fancy-select__option').on('click', $.proxy(this.selectProduct, this));
}
```

Comment: It's due to the scope of `this`. What are you expecting it to be a reference to? Also, what scope are you attempting to call `selectProduct` with?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am expecting it to be a reference to the click event of `.lm-fancy-select__option`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the scope of `this`. In your first example it will be an Element object containing `.lm-fancy-select__option`. In the second example it will be a reference to the object which holds the `binds` property.

> I am expecting it to be a reference to the click event of `.lm-fancy-select__option`

In this case you can retrieve the event from the arguments provided to the event handler and call `$.proxy` with that scope:

```
binds: function() {
  var _this = this; // get reference to parent object    
  $('#sfProductList').on('click', '.lm-fancy-select__option', function(e) {
    $.proxy(_this.selectProduct, e);
  });
}
```

*However it's important to note that this is completely pointless*. You can simplify this logic by just providing the reference of `selectPoduct` to the event handler:

```
binds: function() {
  $('#sfProductList').on('click', '.lm-fancy-select__option', this.selectProduct);
}
```

Now the scope of the `selectProduct` call will be the element itself and the event is available to that function through the first argument provided.

```js
var obj = {
  selectProduct: function(e) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  },
  binds: function() {
    $('#sfProductList').on('click', '.lm-fancy-select__option', this.selectProduct);
  }
}

obj.binds();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sfProductList">
  <div class="lm-fancy-select__option">Foo</div>
  <div class="lm-fancy-select__option">Bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh man, now I feel dumb! "You can simplify this logic by just providing the reference of selectPoduct to the event handler", that worked! It's been a long week...

Comment: FYI, will accept the answer when I am allowed to. There is a timer on Stack Overflow to accept answers, but you answered too damn quick!